# Load multiple fragments when notification is clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-notifications

I have multiple fragments and only one activity in my app. The requirement is that whenever a notification is clicked, two or three fragments should load based on the category so that when the back button is pressed it should display its parent category.

I have two approaches:
1. When notification is clicked, add all the required fragments to back stack and display the last one.
2. When notification is clicked, load only the last one and add all the parent fragments to custom back stack and handle the back button.

After loading the last fragment, the user can go to some other screen also. In this case, I will have to handle two back stacks in case of **Approach 2**.

What should be the best approach to handle this requirement?